# open() function cannot locate files

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pycharm

I’m a fairly new python user and I’m having an issue with the open() function where python isn’t able to find the files that I’m trying to work with. **I’m using Python 3.5, PyCharm CE and macOS Sierra**. I have a feeling the issue is caused by the fact that I’m using a mac and macs come preinstalled with python 2.7, which has caused me issues with things like adjusting filepaths and installing packages in the past.

**Here’s what I’ve tried so far:**

- Referencing just the file name:

  `file = open("file_name.txt", "r").read()`
- Referencing the file from within the folder its in (on my desktop)

  `file = open(“folder_name/file_name.txt", "r").read()`
- Referencing the entire file path:

  `file = open("/Users/username\ 1/Desktop/folder_name/file_name.txt", "r").read()`
- Creating a new directory within the project and manually
  adding files I’m trying to reference to the new directory:

  `print (os.getcwd())`

  `>>> Users/username/PycharmProjects/Project_Name`

  `os.mkdir(“directory_name”)`

  `file = open("/Users/username/PycharmProjects/Project_Name/directory_name/file_name.txt", "r").read()`
- adding both the file while both in the folder sitting on my desktop and  sitting alone on my desktop to the filepath

  `sys.path.append("/Users/User_Name\ 1/Desktop/Folder_name/File_name.txt")`

  `sys.path.append("/Users/User_Name\ 1/Desktop/file_name.txt")`

I’m getting basically this error message or some variation of it:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ‘file_name.txt'
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Do you want to open the file "file_name.txt" or the file "File_name.txt"?
Most operating systems' file names are case-sensitive.

Comment: `sys.path.append` won't do anything useful in your case. It's just python module search path.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> print (os.getcwd()) 
Users/username/PycharmProjects/Project_Name
```

So that's your current working directory. If you want to open a file that's on the desktop, you're going to have to tell Python that's where it is.

You can indicate your home directory ("/Users/username" on OS X or "/home/username" on Linux systems) with "~". Prove it in Python with:

```
>>> os.path.expanduser('~')
"/Users/username"
>>> os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop')
"/Users/username/Desktop"
```

So to open a file that's on your desktop, you can point Python to it with:

```
open(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/filename.txt'))
```